# Better way to access ABI using Truffle in Production?

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, ethereumjs

I would like to know what would be the best way to access ABI.json to interact with the contract using web3.js on the front end?

I create a route (example: /abi.json) pointing to the ABI generated in the truffle's build folder. Is there a better or more performative way?